# Show that the homomorphism is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be the quotient $F_2/\langle a^4,b^4,aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle.$Define the mapping $\phi: \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4 \rightarrow G$ by $\phi(([m]_4,[n]_4))=a^mb^n.$ Show that $\phi$ is isomorphism.

First, if $[m]_4=[c]_4,[n]_4=[d]_4,$ then $\phi(([c]_4,[d]_4))=a^cb^d=a^{[c]_4}b^{[d]_4}$ (since the normal form of elements of $G$ is $a^ib^j$, where $0≤,≤3$) $=a^{[m]_4}b^{[n]_4}=\phi(([m]_4,[n]_4))$, so $\phi$ is well-defined. 
Next, $\phi(([m]_4,[n]_4)+([c]_4,[d]_4))=\phi(([m+c]_4,[n+d]_4))=a^{m+c}b^{n+d}=a^mb^na^cb^d=\phi(([m]_4,[n]_4))\phi(([c]_4,[d]_4)).$ 
 
Therefore, $\phi$ is homomorphism. Now, for any $a^{m}b^{n} \in G$ there exist $([m]_4,[n]_4) \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4$ such that  $\phi(([m]_4[n]_4))=a^{m}b^{n}.$ So, $\phi$ is surjective.

I'm having trouble with showing injectivity. I want to show that $Ker{\phi}=e_1,$ so $\phi$ is injective. How can I prove that
$\phi(([m]_4,[n]_4))=e_2=1 \iff a^mb^n=1 \iff m=0 \text{ and } n=0?$

Answer (score 1):

The quotient $F_2/\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$ is the abelian group $\mathbb Z^2$, and everything else is clear.